# Rotating disc problem

Tags: classical-mechanics

This question comes into my mind this evening.

Suppose I have a rotating disc whose maximum rotation speed is $500$ rpm (say). On this rotating disc I have placed another small rotating disc with same property and in such a way that both can rotate in this configuration. Now if I started the disc below, it starts to rotate with it maximum speed with the smaller disc on its top. After some time i start the smaller disc and it also starts to rotate with maximum speed. So my question is what kind of effect the larger disc will put on the smaller disc if (a) they both rotate in same direction (b) one disc clock wise and other anti-clock wise.

N.B.- I am not a physics student so don't know how to interpret.

Comment: Seems like you question is a bit vague. Your question is "what kind of effect the larger disc will put on the smaller disc"? Precisely what do you mean by "effect"?

Comment: The geometry and engineering of your situation is important. Is the axis of the smaller disk co-linear with the axis of the larger disk, or is it attached to the larger disk at some point away from the axis? Is the smaller disk tilted with respect to the larger? Are you assuming frictionless bearings between each disk and its axis?

Comment: I am assuming the small disc and the large disc both are in colinear alignment. There is no friction. Actually I was wondering, if the bigger disc is rotating at it max speed and then if we start the second disc to it's max speed, will the second disc rotation speed increase, because it's platform (the larger disc) is already in motion or is such analysis in valid?

Comment: If there is no friction and the axle of one is not connected to the other disk, there is no interaction. They rotate independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they rotate in the same direction at the same speed, there will be no effect. This is because the disks do not move relative to one another.

If they rotate at different speeds or in different directions and there is friction between the disks, their speeds will gradually come closer to one another's until their rotation rates are the same.

A good way to think about this is to imagine you are standing on one of the disks. Then the disk you are standing on is holding still, from your perspective. If the other disk is moving, friction will slow it down until it eventually stops.

Comment: What if there is no friction? What if the axles aren't aligned?

Comment: If there is no friction there is of course no interaction between the disks. From OP's a) and b) I think it is clear that the axles are meant to be aligned. Aligned or not the friction will act until there is no relative motion between the disks.